# How to Submit an HTML Form to Google Sheets…without Google Forms

Tags: javascript

I found this site:
https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175

I am trying to create the form as they stipulated but I got undefined in the google sheets for the form fields. Here is my code

```js
var $form = $('form#test-form'),
    url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxLarVG8hcqD6DTXAd5FITK9lZhy_zF-DsBtEVCdAOfah5yT04/exec'

$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serializeObject()
  }).success(
    // do something
  );
})
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Field 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="form_field_1" placeholder="Field 1"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Field 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="form_field_2" placeholder="Field 2"/>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>Field 3</label>
    <input type="text" name="form_field_3" placeholder="Field 3"/>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>Field 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="form_field_4" placeholder="Field 4"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="submit"id="submit-form">Submit</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Hey Clarissa, you can use https://sheetmonkey.io to do this without any Javascript. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if you missed to include JQuery Library only to this post, but it is one of your problems here. First, give reference to Jquery library, like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And when you do, you get an error message, saying that serializeObject is not a function. Again, you can use an external library which creates that function or write your own like so:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

By the way thanks to @ravi_kant_dubey for writing this function, you can see the topic from [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/serializeobject).

And finally do something with that code to see if everything works fine.

```
function(e){console.log(e);}
```

> Anyway, if you run the script below, you can see that the response
> returns without any problems. Which means that it is working.

```js
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

var $form = $('form#test-form'),
    url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxLarVG8hcqD6DTXAd5FITK9lZhy_zF-DsBtEVCdAOfah5yT04/exec'

$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serializeObject()
  }).success(function(e){console.log(e);}
    // do something
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>Field 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="form_field_1" placeholder="Field 1"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Field 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="form_field_2" placeholder="Field 2"/>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>Field 3</label>
    <input type="text" name="form_field_3" placeholder="Field 3"/>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>Field 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="form_field_4" placeholder="Field 4"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="submit"id="submit-form">Submit</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: do you mean like this? http://sseoservices.epizy.com/test.html?form_field_1=dfsdkjfsk&form_field_2=jdklfjdkl&form_field_3=kjfdlkfjksal&form_field_4=kjdfalkfjd

Comment: You need to include Jquery library first, and then insert your code after it. In your second example, Jquery library is loaded later that is why it throws an error saying that `$` is not defined.

Comment: As for your jsfiddle, Jquery library is not included at all. There is a select box over your Javascript code on Jsfiddle Page. Which says `JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS) `. Just click it, and select a Jquery library, and you are good to go.

Comment: Also, you missed to include your button click eventhandler. I mean the one starting with:  `$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {`

Comment: I’m getting a cors error. Any solutions?